# C# to mimic Excel SLOPE function

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, list, math

I'm trying to calculate the slope of two data lists. You can easily calculate this in EXCEL using the SLOPE function. `=SLOPE(A1:A100, B1:B100)`. I'm trying to mimic this function in C# WinForm. Here is my code, it can calculate something, but not the correct number that you would get from the Excel function. Please help me find the error here. Thanks so much!

```
private double Getslope(List<double> ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR, List<double> primaryIndexExcessReturnOverRFR, int months, int go_back = 0)
{
    double slope = 0;
    double sumx = 0, sumy = 0, sumxy = 0, sumx2 = 0;
    for (int i = ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR.Count - 1 - go_back; i > ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR.Count - (1 + months + go_back); i--)
    {
        sumxy += ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR[i] * primaryIndexExcessReturnOverRFR[i];
        sumx += ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR[i];
        sumy += primaryIndexExcessReturnOverRFR[i];
        sumx2 += ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR[i] * ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR[i];      
    }

    return slope = 1 / (((sumxy - sumx * sumy / months) / (sumx2 - sumx * sumx / months)));
}
```

Test data:
`{1.085231224, 2.335034309, 0.346667278}` and
`{3.185231224,3.705034309 , -0.883332722}` should have slope of 0.3373 if you calculate in Excel using `=SLOPE` function. But my code produces 0.47 somehow...

Comment: Some input data and the expected result would be helpful

Comment: {1.085231224, 2.335034309, 0.346667278} and {3.185231224,3.705034309
, -0.883332722} should have slope of 0.3373 if you calculate in Excel using =SLOPE function. But my code produces 0.47 somehow...

Comment: You are very unclear about the input conditions (what does `{1.085231224, 2.335034309, 0.346667278}` and
`{3.185231224,3.705034309 , -0.883332722}` mean at all?); about your formula (what does `months` mean?); and you are not even providing a way to validate the calculations (something which might be easily input in Excel). Can you please improve all this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your formula is wrong

According to the Excel documentation the formula for SLOPE is

[image]

Note also that the first argument to the function is the the `y` values.

It's unclear how `goback` and `months` apply, but it *looks* like this might work:

```
private double Getslope(List<double> ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR, 
                        List<double> primaryIndexExcessReturnOverRFR, 
                        int months, 
                        int go_back = 0)
{
    // calc # of items to skip
    int skip = ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR.Count - go_back - months;

    // get list of x's and y's
    var ys = ProductGrossExcessReturnOverRFR.Skip(skip).Take(months);
    var xs = primaryIndexExcessReturnOverRFR.Skip(skip).Take(months);

    // "zip" xs and ys to make the sum of products easier
    var xys = Enumerable.Zip(xs,ys, (x, y) => new {x = x, y = y});

    double xbar = xs.Average();
    double ybar = ys.Average();

    double slope = xys.Sum(xy => (xy.x - xbar) * (xy.y - ybar)) / xs.Sum(x => (x - xbar)*(x - xbar));

    return slope;
}
```

Comment: @D Stanley, your code get 2.11 which is 1/0.47. So essentially it's the same as mine. int months in my code is the number of data within each list. int go_back in most cases would be 0 by definition, but I use it to deal with Year-To-Date situation in other functions. Shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: @Eddie can you please provide a way to validate your calculations as suggested via comments? For example 3/4 cases. Perhaps it is a rounding problem as far as lots of operations are involved.

Comment: I think @D Stanley just edited his code above and it works now. @ D Stanley would you please tell me what did you change since the first post? Thank you!

Comment: @Eddie you don't need to write @ when you are in the answer of the given user. Also you can take a look at the "Edited X mins ago" link above. But, please, in the future provide much better information as far as what D Stanley did was basically a lucky guess (there wasn't enough information in your question to even know what you wanted for sure). PS: also it would be a good thing if you answer people talking to you.

Comment: @varocarbas I switched the `x`s and `y`s.  SLOPE takes the `y`s as the first argument - I was assuming you were using the first argument for the `x`s.

Comment: OK. Thanks for letting me know but I wasn't the one asking (it was Eddie, who apparently talks just with you). The whole point of my contribution here was realising that my relying-in-decimal-by-default (what has happened to me just during the last months, as explained in a deleted comment) wasn't really applicable here (although, actually speaking, you cannot be sure as far as there multiple multiplications and divisions and you don't have any real control on the number of decimals); I have also explained Eddie that he should post clearer questions, as far as this time was horrible.